# Замена символов в строках

Tags: python

Есть путь к файлу:

```
C:\Users\User\text.txt
```

Как заменить "\" на "/"?

Путь может быть любой

Comment: r"C:\Users\User\text.txt".replace("\\", "/")

Comment: "/".join(r"C:\Users\User\text.txt".split("\\"))

Comment: Возможно, использование os.path.sep будет более уместным

Comment: а зачем? почему просто не использовать `r'C:\Users\User\text.txt'` ?

Comment: Какая вообще задача? Откуда приходит путь и где он используется? Возможно и заменять ничего не надо.

Comment: Да всё уже, спасибо Flowneee

Answer (score -1):

Можно воспользоваться:

```
path = 'C:\Users\User\text.txt'
os.path.normpath(path)
```

Comment: Нельзя. Во-первых, задача заменить "\" на "/", а во-вторых, испробуйте свое решение, например, на "C:\Users\alex\123\567.txt"

Comment: Хм... ваш пример и правда интересен. но на Винде normpath должен же заменить '\' на '/' ? Я думаю, тут именно вопрос с этим контекстом.

Comment: Почему должен? И в Проводнике и в командной строке используется "\". Заменяет на "\\".